# Ignoring newlines with regex in xml

Tags: regex, xml, python-3.x, regex-group, regex-greedy

This is for a project for a very specific use.

I am trying to find how to find any empty text from the xml and replace it with a message.

```
regex = re.compile(r'>\s*</')


replaced = re.sub(regex, ">[!] JSON value does not exist, Check your Json!</", temp)
```

For example filename is blank

```
        <file>               
            <fileType>Mezza</fileType>
            <fileName></fileName>
            <segments>0000</segments>
        </file>
```

and the output would be:

```
         <file>               
            <fileType>Mezza</fileType>
            <fileName>[!] value does not exist!</fileName>
            <segments>0000</segments>
        </file>
```

However I am getting for other parts where there is white space and newline I dont want to have this message, both tag names are different there is a new line and they are closing tags how do I implement this in regex?:

```
</fileName>[!] value does not exist!</file>
```

Comment: Use a space instead of `\s`.

Comment: I need to make sure there is text within those tags.

Comment: I thought you're trying to detect if there's only spaces within the tags.

Comment: Use a real XML parser or XPath to parse XML, not regex.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, another option here we might be having would be to just find `filename`, and replace what we desire inside the tag, with likely an expression such as:

```
(<fileName>)(.+)?(<\/fileName>)
```

if I understand the problem correctly.

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/evxvyR/1/)

If we have fully empty tags, this expression might likely work:

```
(>)()(<\/)
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/bkISjI/1/)

If we will be having empty tags and tags with horizontal spaces, then we would be expanding it to:

```
(>)(|[^\S\r\n]+)(<\/)
```

#### [Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/cwO4em/1/)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(<fileName>)(.+)?(<\/fileName>)"

test_str = ("        <file>               \n"
    "            <fileType>Mezza</fileType>\n"
    "            <fileName></fileName>\n"
    "            <segments>0000</segments>\n"
    "        </file>")

subst = "\\1[!] value does not exist!\\3"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

Comment: Thanks Emma for the reply, but filename is one example.  There are other tags, that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[ \t]*` instead of `\s*`. This will match spaces and tabs, but not newlines. So the code should be:

```
regex = re.compile(r'>[ \t]*</')
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/uizw2d)

Comment: Does python accept the `\h` horizontal whitespace?

Comment: Check the demo, it's printing the message.

Comment: It would probably be better to parse the XML and check the value there, instead of doing it with a regexp.